# How do I manage voice connections from multiple bots in one code?

Tags: discord.js

My code manages multiple and different Discord bots, and to check what bot has to perform a certain action there's an algorithm that looks just like the following:

```js
function getHandlerByClient(client: Discord.Client): (typeof MusicHandler) {
    if (Utils.checkClientByToken(client, Constants.MUSIC1_TOKEN)) return MusicHandler1;
    else if (Utils.checkClientByToken(client, Constants.MUSIC2_TOKEN)) return MusicHandler2;
    else if (Utils.checkClientByToken(client, Constants.MUSIC3_TOKEN)) return MusicHandler3;
    return MusicHandler;
}
```

On previous Discord.js versions I could just execute something like:
`let joinEvent = channel.join();`
and it would work just fine, the correct bot instance would execute that code. Now everything's changed and I have to run:

```js
let connection = DiscordVoice.joinVoiceChannel({
    channelId: channel.id,
    guildId: channel.guild.id,
    adapterCreator: channel.guild.voiceAdapterCreator
});
```

and it doesn't even work as it did before: if I play something on bot#1 and then without having it stopped play something else on bot#2, bot#2 doesn't join the channel and plays everything in bot#1. So whenever I run play on any of the bots, all the others won't join channels until the first one called quits. How can I solve this?

Comment: Looking through the djs voice docs (which are incredibly limited and seem to still be unfinished), as well as the source code for djs voice, it doesn't seem like it was made with the idea of supporting multiple clients in mind. It doesn't really keep track of which client a voice connection belongs to at all, it just keeps track of which guild and channel it belongs to. Because of this, I don't think it's possible to do this using djs voice atm. You would have to either find a module on NPM that can do this, or fork and modify djs voice yourself to make this possible.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if after 3 months my answer will help, but maybe someone will also face this problem.
I struggled all day with the same problem, and to my great fortune I found the answer in the official discord server discord.js.
[solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZNSN.png)

I simply add client.user.id as group identificator and use voiceAdapterCreator from a certain client that i need like this:

```
/* attachedBot.client - the bot client that you want to connect to voice channel */

const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
    channelId: interaction.member.voice.channelId,
    guildId: interaction.guild.id,
    adapterCreator: (await (await attachedBot.client.guilds.fetch()).find(g => g.id === interaction.guild.id).fetch()).voiceAdapterCreator,
    group: attachedBot.client.user.id
});
```

And this works fine for me